# MySQL auto-increment two-part primary key

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-5.7

I'm creating a schema in MySQL that (for the purpose of this question) has two tables:

```
Projects (pid:int) 
Tasks (pid:int,tid:int)
```

Each Project can have many Tasks, and each Task belongs to one Project. I have pid in Projects set up to be the primary key and to auto-increment as projects are added. Ideally, I'd like to construct Tasks so that the primary key for each task is both the pid and the tid. The tid would increment for tasks belonging to the same project but would start at 1 again for each new project.

```
(pid,tid) = (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,2)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)
```

I know I can achieve this effect by making a query to find the highest tid for a project and manually incrementing it for the next task; however, I'd like to do it without the query, if possible. Is there a simpler, more efficient way to implement this functionality (eg something with AUTO_INCREMENT)?

I'm programming in Python 3 with the Flask microframework and MySQL 5.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: You could use a trigger to create the `pid/tid` value whenever you `INSERT` a new task.

Comment: Have you read this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html Seems to work with myisam engines.

Comment: So I would be using the trigger to calculate the tid inside MySQL instead of Python? I could certainly do that!

EDIT: Thanks, Kay! That link is just what I'm looking for! (I suppose I should acquaint myself with the MySQL manual now)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If `tid` was the primary key of Tasks then `pid` just becomes a foreign key back into Projects; there shouldn't be a need to have a multi-part primary key here.

Comment: My reasoning is that if the task is left unnamed, tid will be displayed to the user in the form "(Project Name) Task #tid". I'm trying to avoid a situation where a new project is created and the first task is displayed as "(MyProject) Task #4018" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MyIsam its possible. I just tried from the documentation myself. Just fit it to your needs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html